# предупреждение: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

Tags: qt, qt5, opengl, libpng

У меня при сборке "выпрыгнуло" предупреждение:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB
```

Почему эта предупреждение появляется что я должен сделать что бы решить эту проблему ??

---

Вопрос является [переводом с английского](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile) , но честно сказать он мне понравился и я сам с такой проблемой столкнулся.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ibpng-1.6 более жестко проверяет профили ICC, чем предыдущие. Вы можете игнорировать предупреждение. Чтобы избавиться от него, удалите кусок iCCP из изображения PNG.

Некоторые приложения (в моём случае OpenGL)  рассматривают предупреждения как ошибки; если вы используете такое приложение, вам нужно удалить iCCP кусок из изображения PNG. Это можно сделать с помощью любого из множества редакторов PNG (по правде говоря стандартный paint в windows у меня не смог). Пример редактор  ImageMagick's : `convert in.png out.png.`

Что бы удалить дефектный кусок (iCCP) из всех файлов PNG  лежащих в директории можно воспользоваться командой `mogrify *.png` при условии, что ваш ImageMagick был собран с помощью libpng16(запустите такой командой `convert -list format | grep PNG` что бы быть уверренным в том что собираете в "верных" настройках).

Если вы хотите узнать, какие файлы нужно исправлять, а не слепо обрабатывать их все, вы можете запустить `pngcrush -n -q *.png`, где `-n` означает, что вы не переписываете файлы и  `- q` означает подавление "технической" части вывода, за исключением предупреждений.   К сожалению, в pngcrush еще нет опции для подавления всех "технических" сообщений, кроме предупреждений.

---

Бинарные релизы ImageMagick [здесь](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

---

Для Android-проектов (Android Studio) перейдите в папку res.

Пример: `C:\AndroidProjects\{your_project_folder}\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\mogrify *.png`

---

Используйте [`pngcrush`](https://pmt.sourceforge.io/pngcrush/) чтобы удалить неправильный профиль sRGB из файла png:

```
 pngcrush -ow -rem allb -reduce file.png
```

- `ow` будет перезаписывать входной файл
- `rem allb` удалит все вспомогательные куски, кроме tRNS и gAMA
- `reduce` сохраняет цвет и глубину

На выходе консоли вы должны увидеть `Removed the sRGB chunk`. , и, возможно, больше сообщений об удалении кусков iCCP. В конечном итоге вы получите меньший оптимизированный файл png. Когда команда перезапишет исходный файл, обязательно создайте резервную копию или контроль версий (гит_хаб, тартуисеХГ и т.д.).

---

**Решение** (мне это вариант нравится потому что он в Qt-е :3 )

Не корректный файл может быть исправлен :

1. Открываем картинку(некорректный файл) с помощью [`QPixmap::load`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#load)
2. Сохраняем картинку(уже корректный файл) на диск с помощью  [`QPixmap::save`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#save-1)

**Примечание** это решение использует [Qt билиотеку](https://www.qt.io/).

**Пример:**

Вот минимальный пример, который я написал на C++, чтобы продемонстрировать, как реализовать предлагаемое решение:

```
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.load("badProfileImage.png");

QFile file("goodProfileImage.png");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
pixmap.save(&file, "PNG");
```

Полный исходный код "GUI приложение", основано на этом примере, доступно в [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-FixPng).

---

Вы можете исправить это в фотошопе.... У меня есть CC2015, но я уверен, что такая возможность присутствует во всех версиях.

1. Откройте ваш .png файл
2. File -> Save As и в открывшемся диалоговом окне **снимите флажок "ICC Profile: sRGB IEC61966-2.1"**
3. снимите флажок "As a Copy"
4. Смело сохраняйте свой "новый" оригинальный .png.
5. Двигайтесь своей жизнью, зная, что вы удалили маленький кусочек зла из этого мира.

---

Я использовал функцию `«mogrify * .png»` ImageMagik. Однако у меня были изображения, зарытые в под папках, поэтому я использовал этот простой скрипт [Python](https://www.python.org/) для применения ко всем изображениям во всех под папках и думал, что он может помочь другим людям:

```
import os
import subprocess

def system_call(args, cwd="."):
    print("Running '{}' in '{}'".format(str(args), cwd))
    subprocess.call(args, cwd=cwd)
    pass

def fix_image_files(root=os.curdir):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
        # sys.stdout.write('.')
        for dir in dirs:
            system_call("mogrify *.png", "{}".format(os.path.join(path, dir)))


fix_image_files(os.curdir)
```

---

Используя первый метод решения сего вопроса изменил вид запроса :

```
find . -name "*.png" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 pngcrush_1_8_8_w64.exe -n -q > pngError.txt 2>&1
```

Я использовал find и xargs, потому что pngcrush не мог обрабатывать множество аргументов (которые были возвращены `** / *. Png`). Параметры `-print0` и `-0` необходимы для обработки имен файлов, содержащих пробелы.

Затем выполните поиск в вывод для этих строк: `iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited.`

```
./Installer/Images/installer_background.png:
Total length of data found in critical chunks = 11286
pngcrush: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
```

И для каждого из них, запустить mogrify, чтобы исправить их.

```
mogrify ./Installer/Images/installer_background.png
```

Это предотвращает возможность индексации будто бы все png файлы изменены, когда только некоторые из них действительно были изменены. Кроме того, у этого метода есть преимущество, чтобы точно показать, какие файлы были неисправны.

Я тестировал это на Windows с консолью Cygwin и оболочкой zsh. И еще спасибо первому варианту(автор которого [глен](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2031419/glenn-randers-pehrson) ) за точное пояснение как эту проблему можно решить.

---

вот более простой способ исправить эту проблему с Mac OS с помощью Homebrew:

```
> install homebrew if it is not installed yet
$brew install libpng
$pngfix --strip=color --out=file2.png file.png
```

или сделать с каждым файлом в текущем каталоге:

```
mkdir tmp; for f in ./*.png; do pngfix --strip=color --out=tmp/"$f" "$f"; done
```

Homebrew создаст фиксированную копию для каждого файла png в текущем каталоге и поместит его в подкаталог tmp. После этого, если все в порядке, вам просто нужно переопределить исходные файлы.

Иной совет- использовать приложения Keynote и Preview для создания иконок. Я рисую их, используя Keynote, размером около 120x120 пикселей, над слайдом с белым фоном (опция для редактирования многоугольников - это замечательно!). Перед экспортом в Preview я рисую прямоугольник вокруг значка (без заливки или тени, только контур размером около 135x135) и скопируйте все в буфер обмена. После этого вам просто нужно открыть его с помощью инструмента «Просмотр» с помощью «Создать из буфера обмена», выбрать область размером 128x128 пикселей вокруг значка, скопировать, снова использовать «Создать из буфера обмена» и экспортировать его в PNG. Вам не нужно будет запускать инструмент pngfix.

---

Используя программу просмотра изображений IrfanView в Windows, я просто сохранил изображение PNG и исправил проблему.

---

Попробовав пару предложений на этой странице, я остановился на использовании  pngcrush. Вы можете использовать скрипт bash ниже для рекурсивного обнаружения и исправления плохих профилей png. Просто передайте ему полный путь к каталогу, который вы хотите найти для png-файлов.

```
fixpng "/path/to/png/folder"
```

скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=$(find "$1" -type f -iname '*.png')

FIXED=0
for f in $FILES; do
    WARN=$(pngcrush -n -warn "$f" 2>&1)
    if [[ "$WARN" == *"PCS illuminant is not D50"* ]] || [[ "$WARN" == *"known incorrect sRGB profile"* ]]; then
        pngcrush -s -ow -rem allb -reduce "$f"
        FIXED=$((FIXED + 1))
    fi
done

echo "$FIXED errors fixed"
```

---

некоторые справочные данные по этому поводу:

> Некоторые изменения в версии libpng 1.6+ приводят к тому, что он
>   выдаёт предупреждение или даже неправильно работает с исходным
>   профилем HP / MS sRGB, что приводит к следующему предупреждению
>   `libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile` . Старый
>   профиль использует стандарт белой точки D50, когда в новом стандарте D65 является белой точкой .
>   Этот профиль не редкость, используеться в Adobe Photoshop, хотя он по
>   умолчанию не был встроен в изображения.

(источник: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libpng_errors)

> Обнаружение ошибок было улучшено в некоторых элементах.в частности, читатель 
>   iCCP элемента теперь делает довольно полную проверку базового
>   формата.Некоторые неудачные профили, которые были ранее приняты,
>   теперь отклонены, в частности, очень старый сломанный профиль
>   Microsoft / HP sRGB.  Требование спецификации PNG, что только
>   изображения с оттенками серого могут отображаться на изображениях с
>   типом цвета 0 или 4, и даже если изображение содержит только серые
>   пиксели, теперь применяются только профили RGB в изображениях с типом
>   цвета 2, 3 или 6. Элементу sRGB разрешено появляться на изображениях с
>   любым типом цвета.

(источник: https://forum.qt.io/topic/58638/solved-libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile-drive-me-nuts/16)

Answer (score 3):

Сохраните нужный вам графический объект в формате .PNG
откройте Photoshop, создайте новый проект, в самом низу есть меню, "Цветовой профиль".
Выбираете самую первую опцию, "Отменить управление цветом в документе". Жмете ОК.
Копируете ваше изображение в проект, сохраняете в формате .PNG.
Наслаждаетесь результатом без всплывающей ошибки.

Comment: спасибо добрый друг, это работает

Answer (score 1):

Эту проблему можно легко решить в фотошопе.
Открой фотошоп и выполни: **Edit** > **Assign Profile** > **Don't Color Manage This Document**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ничем не отличается от [предыдущего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/980685/178576)